# How to access "statically" instance members of types?

Tags: c#, compile-time

I would like to access "statically" (i.e. in compile time) given instance members of types (of course to retrieve static properties of them, not actual values or something like this).

Consider:

```
interface IFoo
{
  int X { get; }
}
```

I would like to access `X` directly to retrieve what is known in compile time, for example:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(IFoo::X).Name);
```

*Reflection is runtime, I am asking about compile-time.*

Comment: You´re looking for `nameof(Foo.X)`? Or in other words you want to query a members metadata like its type or name? You may use reflection for this. How to do this goes far beyond a single question here.

Comment: If you're not *just* looking for the name, it sounds like you want the mythical `infoof` operator: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/21/in-foof-we-trust-a-dialogue/

Comment: @HimBromBeere, thank you, I know reflection, but for this I need instance, so this is not compile time nor static access.

Comment: You don´t need an instance to retrieve its metadata, because that metadata is staically bound to a **type**, not a single **instance**. Hopwever you´re right that it´s runtime-information.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thank you :-), I am not looking for a name (actually I gave example with type, not name), but I would need to have syntax to access members in static fashion.

Comment: "Reflection is runtime, I am asking about compile-time. " Then the answer is "there is no way to do it"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no C# operator to refer to members in a compile-time type-safe way like this. It's a [feature that is frequently requested, but really difficult to design well](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/21/in-foof-we-trust-a-dialogue/). The `nameof` operator introduced in C# 6 manages to skirt around most of the design issues, while satisfying *most* use cases.

Even if the supposed `infoof` operator *did* exist, it's unlikely that there's be a way of accessing specific properties from it (such as the name of the return type of the property) at compile time.

If the "compile-time" part is important to you for the sake of *safety* rather than in order to actually evaluate the name at compile-time, there are ways that could work. For example:

```
public static class TypeHelpers<TInput>
{
    public static Type GetReturnType<TOutput>(Func<TInput, TOutput> func) =>
        typeof(TOutput);
}
```

Then:

```
Type returnType = TypeHelpers<IFoo>.GetReturnType(foo => foo.X);
Console.WriteLine(returnType.FullName); // System.Int32
```

That would be better than having to *find* the member at execution time, but it's still requesting the type name at execution time.

Comment: Ah, for the resulting `Name` I would use it in runtime, but entire access is verified in compile time. I am not here about performance, but validity. Using reflection it is easy to make an error, while with (wished) static access everything could be verified in compile time, so my `typeof(IFoo::X).Name` is 100% valid while translation this to reflection is error prone, one typo more or less will still compile just fine. AWESOME, you are reading my mind, scary :-).

Comment: @astrowalker: Right, I believe that the lambda expression approach should avoid that typo problem then, although it's still a little ugly.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: you can´t do this at **compile**-time. You could do it at **runtime** using reflection, though.

However there´s some assist to get at least the name using `nameof`:

```
nameof(IFoo.Name)
```

This won´t give you the compile-time-type of that member, though.

The following feature never made it to a language-feature, although there´s some request existing for it:

```
typeof(IFoo.Name)
```

or even the `infoof`-operator mentioned by Eric Lipert (see Jons answer).